# How to create model maker NDBI indice using Landsat 8?

Tags: remote-sensing, image

I'm having trouble making the model for NDBI (custom made in ERDAS 9.2) using Landsat 8 image?

As a result of running the model I'm getting a white image.

Comment: Unfortunately, I changed computers but what can I say is that I made 2 spots for the band that links to a formula circle below via arrows then that is linked to another spot/box for output. Basically the input is Band 5 and 7 (NIR and SWIR). The formula: (NIR-SWIR)/(NIR+SWIR).

Comment: Did you make sure that your output raster is casted as a floating point raster? Since your result is an index, the result will be between -1 and 1, so that important parts of the informative value are in the decimal places. If your raster is casted as whole numbers, you will have a maximum of 2 values (1 and 0) for an unsigned raster and 3 (1, 0 and -1) for a signed raster with possible negative values.